# I have male nema L14 30 P PLUG OFF OF MY PANEL

Tags: wiring

I have a Nema L14 30p plug off my power panel and want to run a short extension with multi female 110 plug on the other end . How do I do this conversion ?

Comment: Which 110 plug are we talking about here? A 5-15 or 5-20 (typical), or a 5-30 (unusual)?

Comment: Was this male plug intended as a generator inlet?  Is there an interlock that prevents it being hot?

Comment: Tyson's question is super important to solving your problem.

Comment: Can you post pics of the male plug on the panel, let's make sure we are all talked about the same thing, also take one of the entire panel, showing all the breakers.

Comment: Tyson. Thank you for your question. Yes this plug was set up for generator inlet and it has an interlock

Comment: Three phase  thank you for your question.  Just looking for standard 110 plugs so we can plug in computers